# How to exclude scheduled task from Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-task-scheduler, windows-defender

I have scheduled task that should run every two hours, with the following command line action:

- Program: `mshta`
- Arguments: `vbscript:Execute("CreateObject(""Wscript.Shell"").Run ""powershell -NoLogo -Command """"& 'X:\Path\To\Custom\powershellScript.ps1'"""""", 0 : window.close")`

Every two hours, instead of the task getting run, i'm getting:

[image: Found some malware Windows Defender is removing it]

and in Defender history:

[image: Detected item Trojan:Win32/Powerssere.G]

I don't want to stop Windows Defender, because of potential security implications of doing so. **Is there a way to add exclusion in Defender to ignore the task?**.

I tried adding both script path, folder, `mshta.exe` and `powershell.exe` to exclusions, also `ps1` to file types. Nothing works.

By the way, Defender doesn't remove the task, or the script that should be run, just stops it from running.

**Clarification**:

- It must be run in background, no window should pop out when the task is run, it has to be run with the user if he's logged in, i don't want to store password/run with other user account or highest privileges.
- The script has to be executed as the logged in user. The purpose of it is to change the wallpaper for the logged in user to downloaded one (`$picturePath` variable). Excerpt:

```
    $registryPropertyPath = "HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\"
    $registryPropertyName = "Wallpaper"
    $wallpaperProperty = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $registryPropertyPath -Name $registryPropertyName).WallPaper
    if ($wallpaperProperty -ne $picturePath) {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPropertyPath -Name $registryPropertyName -Value $picturePath
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt 20; $i++) {
            RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True
        }
    }
```

Comment: #1 Ignoring the script host and powershell is a really terrible idea. These are very common threat vectors that need to be scanned.

Comment: #2 Why are you using Wscript to call powershell? Why not just run your script from Task Sched? That should fix the detection problem.

Comment: @HackSlash because running it normally causes window to pop out every two hours. This is a desktop machine, I don't want it, it should be run completely in background.

Comment: The script has to be run as logged-in user (_Run only when user is logged on_).

Comment: ..so your task runs a HTA which runs a VBScript which runs PowerShell which runs rundll32 to call a function not even meant to be called from rundll32? Don't be surprised if other programs find it suspicious.

Comment: But for a start, have you tried 1) running VBScript via `wscript` rather than MSHTA? 2) avoiding the PowerShell layer and doing everything via VBScript? It can read and write registry, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for this...

> My script invokes RUNDLL32.EXE
>   USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True to update wallpaper,
>   which must be executed when user is logged in, it won't work otherwise

You are trying to use a remote user context, to run in a local user context. This is a Windows security boundary, always has been. So, not a PowerShell issue.

PowerShell will not natively allow this, because of this Windows security boundary violation.

Also, there are other ways to do this, vs the method you are trying.

If you really need to do this, firstly, in an enterprise, that is what GPO's are for. There are hose that can't use GPO for whatever the reason. So, they try this approach and it does not work, because it's not designed to.

So, if you need to use a remote local user context, then you need to use a 3rdP option, like SysInternals PSExec as discussed here...

> How to run a program for a remotely logged in user in Windows
>
> You can do this with PsExec, be sure to have the right permissions to
>   run applications for him. psexec \computer -u user -i -d command
>
> -u means user, -i makes it interactive so the user sees it, -d makes sure the command doesn't wait
>
> 'superuser.com/questions/176249/how-to-run-a-program-for-a-remotely-logged-in-user-in-windows'

... or AutoIT.

You could also create a native .ps1 script, doing something like this...

```
cp "image.jpg" \\<IP>\C$
$RemoteReg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users', "<IP>")
$WallPaper= $RemoteReg.OpenSubKey("S-1-5-21-780093305-1579027723-3042286928-500\Control Panel\Desktop",$True)
$WallPaper.SetValue("Wallpaper","C:\image.jpg")
```

... and set it as a RunOnce option (Registry) for the user.

You could create a once time Scheduled Task to run once at logon for the user or other point in the day.

So, step back a bit and think about other options vs jamming this effort that is really not designed to get you where you are trying to go.

Answer (score 3):

Again, as noted, if you do this, it's simply a virus type action and should be blocked.

As @HackSlash notes, that is the correct way to do this.

When you say a Windows pop-out because of this, and it should because you are starting a new shell and the shell has to launch and show as active. You can just add the WindowStyle property -minimize or -hidden switch to diminish that.

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6
>
> PowerShell[.exe]
>          [-Command { - |  [-args ]
>                        |  [] } ]
>          [-EncodedCommand ]
>          [-ExecutionPolicy ]
>          [-File  []]
>          [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
>          [-Mta]
>          [-NoExit]
>          [-NoLogo]
>          [-NonInteractive]
>          [-NoProfile]
>          [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
>          [-PSConsoleFile  | -Version ]
>          [-Sta]
>          [-WindowStyle ]
>
> PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?
>
> -WindowStyle
>
> Sets the window style for the session. Valid values are Normal,
>   Minimized, Maximized and Hidden.

Or this approach, since even the above the window will still momentarily flash.

> Howto hide a PowerShell prompt
>
> http://jeffwouters.nl/index.php/2015/09/howto-hide-a-powershell-prompt

Or this one

> Sneaky PowerShell Trick: Run Completely Without A Window
>
> static void Main(string[] args) {
>       var powershell = PowerShell.Create();
>       powershell.AddScript(@" Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp | out-file c:\temp\shh.txt ");
>       var handler = powershell.BeginInvoke();
>       while (!handler.IsCompleted)
>           Thread.Sleep(200);
>       powershell.EndInvoke(handler);
>       powershell.Dispose(); }
>
> https://workingsysadmin.com/sneaky-powershell-trick-run-completely-without-a-window

Comment: I know that is the correct way to do that, in my task scheduler I have a lot of scripts scheduled this way, but they can be run in background (because e.g. they just download, compress and save something). This cannot. See my clarification in the original post.

Comment: _You can just add the WindowStyle property -minimize or -hidden switch to diminish that._. No. As you wrote, it still is popping out for a few miliseconds. I tried that before. The other solution also doesn't work - the window still pops out, the 2nd is C#, which i don't really want to bother with.

Answer (score 1):

The detection event comes from your use of an unsafe method to call PowerShell. Don't use Wscript to call Powershell, only a virus would do that. ;-D

Try this method of calling your script:

- Program: `powershell.exe`
- Arguments: `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden X:\Path\To\Custom\powershellScript.ps1`

Comment: Yes, i know of that method, but it causes the window to pop out. See my clarification in the original post.

Comment: Run it as a different user and allow it to run when not logged in. This will prevent it from running under your current user context.

Comment: My script invokes `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters 1, True` to update wallpaper, which must be executed when user is logged in, it won't work otherwise.

Comment: Let's add "-NoLogo -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Hidden"